# vue js передача параметра при клике

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel5, laravel-5.7

подскажите, как передать параметр при удалении?

```
<template>
    <div class="blacklist">
        <form action="" class="search">
            <input type="text"  v-model="url"  name="url" placeholder="Что ищем?" value="" >
        </form>
        <div class="preloader" v-if="loading"><div class="ball"></div><div class="ball1"></div></div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Запрещенный URL-адрес</th>
                <th>Причина запрета</th>
                <th>Действия</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody v-for="blackl in blacklist">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ blackl.id}}</td>
                <td>{{ blackl.url}}</td>
                <td>{{ blackl.content}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="data-action">
                        <a href="" class="btn-edit"><svg class="editp"><use xlink:href="#editp"></use></svg></a>
                        <button type="button" @click="deleteb(blackl.id)"  class="btn-delete"><svg class="deletep"><use xlink:href="#deletep"></use></svg></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        el: '#admin-blacklist',
        data: function(){
            return {
                loading: false,
                url: null,
                blacklist: []
            }
        },
        watch: {
            url(after, before) {
                this.fetch();
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.update()
        },
        methods: {
            fetch: function (){
                this.loading = true;
                axios.post('/admin/blacklist/search', {  url: this.url } )
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.blacklist = response.data
                        this.loading = false;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
            update: function () {
                this.loading = true;
                axios.get('/admin/blacklist/list').then((response) => {
                    this.blacklist = response.data
                    this.loading = false;
                });
            },
            deleteb: function () {
                axios.post('/admin/blacklist/delete', {  id: blackl.id } )
                    .then((response) => {
                        response.data
                        toast.fire({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Удалено!'.response.data.id
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передали пераметр, но не прийняли его у своём методе.

```
deleteb(id) {
            axios.post('/admin/blacklist/delete', { id } )
                .then((response) => {
                    response.data
                    toast.fire({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Удалено!'.response.data.id
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {});
        }
```